# Parts of Loop Cut snapping to nearby edges?

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

I'm fairly new to Blender and I am trying to follow a tutorial. It's wanting me to make edges clearer using loop cuts instead of making creases.

My problem is that it makes the cut just fine, but if I try to move it (while making the cut or after placing it with right-click) some of the vertices snap to nearby, already-made vertices like in the photo shown below. Neither proportional editing nor auto-merge are on. There is a subdivision modifer, but it does the same thing when I turn that off.

Is there a setting I'm missing or do I need to fix something with the mesh?

[image: Loop Cut Problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the mirror modifier, the merge distance is set to 0.5 meters. That's too much, that's probably why the vertices are snapping to the middle.

[image]

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as the solution by clicking on the check mark :)